# How to write fast modules like numpy for python?

Tags: python, c++, c, api, module

How can we write a massive - fast module for python? I mean how they write a module like **numpy** that executes heavy pieces of code in python *(which is very slow)* so fast? Are they using the C/Python API for that matter? Or it's something else?

Comment: Checkout [How Fast Numpy Really is and Why?](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-fast-numpy-really-is-e9111df44347)

Comment: *"executes heavy pieces of code in python (which is very slow) so fast?"* - because it executes compiled C code, not Python. *"Are they using the C/Python API for that matter?"* - yes, they are using the C Python API for sure.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli is correct - it's ironic we have modules for Python being written in C.

Comment: @Johnny not really. Any language has similar features that permit embedding or calling native code. Performance optimization is a thing. Also, Python itself is written in C.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli of course, it's just interesting that most packages for a language are made in a different language. Like writing an English book in French.

Comment: @Johnny completely different thing but ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension can be written in C/C++ with connectors to other python objects and functions.

The official python documentation has a [C/C++ API reference](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html)